# How can I get an array of random keys from an object, as opposed to a full list?

Tags: javascript

Rather than getting, for example, the first 5 keys from an object with 10 keys:

```
var keys = Object.keys(brain.layers[this.layer]).slice(0, 5);
```

I'd like to get 5 of the keys at random. I know of bulky, long, roundabout ways of doing it, such as something like this:

```
function getRandomNumber(n1, n2) { ... }
var list = [];
var count = 0;

function choose(arr, count, list, max) {
  for (let prop in arr) {
    var choice = Math.round(getRandomNumber(0, 1));
    if (choice === 1 && count < max && !list.includes(arr[prop])) {
      list.push(arr[prop]);
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count >= max) {
    return list;
  } else {
    choose(arr, count, list, max)
  }
}
```

But I was wondering if there's a simpler, more elegant solution.

Comment: `var keys = Object.keys(brain.layers[this.layer]).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 5);`

Comment: @JaromandaX <3!

Comment: although - `var keys = Object.keys(brain.layers[this.layer]).sort(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1).slice(0, 5);` seems to be "more" random for some reason

Answer (score 0):

To get truly a truly (pseudo)random sort use something like an in place random sort.

```
let arrRand=(a,i=a.length)=>{while(i){a.push(a.splice(Math.random()*i--|0,1)[0])}}
let keys = Object.keys(brain.layers[this.layer])
randSort(keys)
keys=keys.slice(0,5)
```

This takes an array and the array length though if it is a modern browser you can use default arguments for that. Warning it modifies the passed in array.